# How to resize multiple images from a folder, convert them into grayscale and save them into another folder?

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing

I have written some code in Python for resizing and converting images to grayscale from a folder and want to save them in another folder. When I compile the code, it shows no output and gives no error. I am sharing the whole code that I have written so far so I can find my error. This is my first question here.

```python
from PIL import Image               # to load images
from IPython.display import display # to display images
import cv2
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
img_path = r"C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\hamza\h1.png"
im= Image.open(img_path)
print('{}'.format(im.format)) 
print('Size: {}'.format(im.size))
print('image mode:{}'.format(im.mode))
im.show()

img_list = []
resized_list = []
for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\hamza\*.png'):
    print(filename)
    img=Image.open(filename)
    img_list.append(img)
    img_list=img_list[:2000]

for image in resized_list:
    if image not in resized_list:
        resized_list.append(img)
        resized_list=(resized_list[:2000])
        img=image.resize((500,500))
        rl=cv2.imread('resized_list') 
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(rl, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite('resized images *.png', gray_image)
```

Comment: No output means that it doesn't print `filename`s too? If so the path could be wrong.
Furthermore the second loop isn't very clear: you are cycling on resized_list (empty) elements and checking if them are not into it.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to hold lists of the contents of thousands of images unnecessarily in memory... you just place unreasonable load on your computer. By all means get a list of filenames but then read, convert, write one at a time, or multiprocess 4 at a time, but don't load 4,000 all at once. Also, avoid mixing OpenCV and PIL, you will confuse yourself.

Comment: You can also do this in one line without writing any code using **ImageMagick**. `mkdir OUTPUT; magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -colorspace gray -resize 500x500\! *.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import cv2
import glob

for filename in glob.glob(r'your\path\*.png'):
    print(filename)
    img=cv2.imread(filename) 
    rl=cv2.resize(img, (500,500))
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(rl, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite(f'{filename}.resized.png', gray_image)
```

Comment: The question asks how to save the results to another folder. I dont see you doing that

Comment: Yes, you can choose the folder you like: `cv2.imwrite(f'folder\\you\\like\\{os.path.basename(filename)}', gray_image)`

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help. I have tried the above code.that works fine.But when I run again the code, it saves again the whole images and make duplicates. How can I remove those duplicates and I have used this code:    
`cv2.imwrite(f'folder\\you\\like\\{os.path.basename(filename)}', gray_image)`           
for saving the images after convertion but it doesn't work.     .@DPD

Comment: @Usama Ali The duplicates are there because the script opens all images in the folder, also the converted images if you save them in the same folder. Which error gives you the second version? Maybe there are some issues with Windows path (using Linux I don't know them so well): you can try using the `os.path.join` function `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join( your_dir, os.path.basename(filename)) , gray_image)`

Comment: Thank you...@DPD- But I have you used the same code for saving files in different folder  but it's not working. Here is my code                                                             `import glob
import cv2
dpath=r'C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\grayscale images*.png'
for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\hamza\*.png'):
    print(filename)
    img=cv2.imread(filename) 
    rl=cv2.resize(img, (40,50))
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(rl, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dpath,filename), gray_image)`... @DPD-

Comment: @Usama your dpath is invalid: you haven't to add the file name, but only the folder (furthermore * is invalid when saving a file): `dpath=r'C:\Users\usama\Documents\FYP-Data\FYP Project Data\grayscale images\'`